# How to use a function that returns multiple values in dplyr::across()?

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I want to perform several operations on multiple columns and I can use `dplyr::across()` to do it that way:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(x=1:5, p1=x*2, p2=x*4, p3=x*5)
r1 = df %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with("p"), c(inf=~.x-1, sup=~.x+1)))
r1
#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#>       x    p1    p2    p3 p1_inf p1_sup p2_inf p2_sup p3_inf p3_sup
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     4     5      1      3      3      5      4      6
#> 2     2     4     8    10      3      5      7      9      9     11
#> 3     3     6    12    15      5      7     11     13     14     16
#> 4     4     8    16    20      7      9     15     17     19     21
#> 5     5    10    20    25      9     11     19     21     24     26
names(r1)
#>  [1] "x"      "p1"     "p2"     "p3"     "p1_inf" "p1_sup" "p2_inf" "p2_sup"
#>  [9] "p3_inf" "p3_sup"
```

However, this is not very scalable if the function calculates a lot of things as it would be evaluated twice.

Instead, it would be nice if I could use a function that calculates the things that need to be calculated, and then returns a list of the 2 (or more) results.

For instance, consider this example:

```r
#perform heavy calculation on x2 and return 2 flavours of it
f = function(x) {
    x2=x #wow, such heavy, very calculate
    Sys.sleep(1)
    data.frame(inf=x2-10, sup=x2+10)
}

r2 = df %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with("p"), f, .names="{.col}_{.fn}"))
r2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>       x    p1    p2    p3 p1_1$inf  $sup p2_1$inf  $sup p3_1$inf  $sup
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     4     5       -8    12       -6    14       -5    15
#> 2     2     4     8    10       -6    14       -2    18        0    20
#> 3     3     6    12    15       -4    16        2    22        5    25
#> 4     4     8    16    20       -2    18        6    26       10    30
#> 5     5    10    20    25        0    20       10    30       15    35
names(r2)
#> [1] "x"    "p1"   "p2"   "p3"   "p1_1" "p2_1" "p3_1"
map_chr(r2, class)
#>            x           p1           p2           p3         p1_1         p2_1 
#>    "integer"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric" "data.frame" "data.frame" 
#>         p3_1 
#> "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Using `rbind()` instead of `data.frame()` would end in the same result with slightly different names (`p1_1$inf` becomes `p1_1[,"inf"]`) and a different class (`data.frame` becomes `c("matrix", "array")`.

Moreover, when using a single function, `{.fn}` is the position of the function so there are naming issues.

I also tried to `unnest()` the result but with no success.

Is there a way to get the exact result of my first output using a function in `across()`?

Comment: Couldn't you store the heavy calculation result `x2` in a new column/data.frame, apply the next steps (`inf`/`sup`) to it using `mutate`? Join in back to the original data.frame if you are using a new data.frame.

Comment: @MartinGal Indeed, if there is no simpler solution, that is the way I might do it. But I'm pretty sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT in recent versions

Since `dplyr 1.1.0` (2023-01-29), `across()` has a `.unpack` argument that you only need to set to `TRUE` for this to work.

#### Original answer:

Actually, this has been considered in an issue on the Github of `dplyr`: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5563#issuecomment-721769342.

There, @romainfrancois gives an incredibly useful solution as this `unpackross()` function:

```r
library(tidyverse)
f = function(x) tibble(inf=x-10, sup=x+10)
unpackross = function(...) {
    out = across(...)
    tidyr::unpack(out, names(out), names_sep = "_")
}

df = tibble(x=1:5, p1=x*2, p2=x*4, p3=x*5)
r2 = df %>% 
    mutate(unpackross(starts_with("p"), f, .names="{.col}_{.fn}"))
r2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#>       x    p1    p2    p3 p1_1_inf p1_1_sup p2_1_inf p2_1_sup p3_1_inf p3_1_sup
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     4     5       -8       12       -6       14       -5       15
#> 2     2     4     8    10       -6       14       -2       18        0       20
#> 3     3     6    12    15       -4       16        2       22        5       25
#> 4     4     8    16    20       -2       18        6       26       10       30
#> 5     5    10    20    25        0       20       10       30       15       35
names(r2)
#>  [1] "x"        "p1"       "p2"       "p3"       "p1_1_inf" "p1_1_sup"
#>  [7] "p2_1_inf" "p2_1_sup" "p3_1_inf" "p3_1_sup"
map_chr(r2, class)
#>         x        p1        p2        p3  p1_1_inf  p1_1_sup  p2_1_inf  p2_1_sup 
#> "integer" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 
#>  p3_1_inf  p3_1_sup 
#> "numeric" "numeric"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Hopefully, there will be an `unpack` parameter in `across()` one day! (add a +1 on my suggestion [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5563#issuecomment-950731022) if you agree)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help you ?

```
library(tidyverse)

f = function(x, y) {
  x2=x
  tibble(!!paste0(y, '_inf') := x2-10, 
         !!paste0(y, '_sup') := x2+10)
}

imap_dfc(select(df, starts_with('p')), f)

#  p1_inf p1_sup p2_inf p2_sup p3_inf p3_sup
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     -8     12     -6     14     -5     15
#2     -6     14     -2     18      0     20
#3     -4     16      2     22      5     25
#4     -2     18      6     26     10     30
#5      0     20     10     30     15     35
```

Bind to orignal `df`.

```
bind_cols(df %>% select(-starts_with('p')), 
          imap_dfc(select(df, starts_with('p')), f))
```

Comment: Great answer! If we assume that column `x` is an ID column, is there an easy way to keep this column and apply your `f` to the remaining `starts_with("p")`-columns? I'm asking, because I usally try to avoid `bind_cols` in favour of a `*_join` function. But I don't see an obivious solution here to keep `x`.

Comment: Yeah..me neither. I think the `bind_cols` solution should be straight forward and should work.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as you have completed your heavy calculations, resulting in a nested dataframe, so, all you need is to convert it to a flat form, maybe some `mutate()`s + `rename` could help?

```
r2 <- df %>% 
mutate(across(2:4, f, .names="{.col}_{.fn}")) %>% 
mutate(across(5:7, .names = ("{.col}_inf"), .fn = ~ .x[,1] )  ) %>%
mutate(across(5:7, .names = ("{.col}_sup"), .fn = ~ .x[,2] )  ) %>% 
rename_with(.fn = ~ gsub("_1_", "_", .x)) %>% 
select(-contains("_1"))

> r2
# A tibble: 5 x 10
      x    p1    p2    p3 p1_inf p2_inf p3_inf p1_sup p2_sup p3_sup
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     2     4     5     -8     -6     -5     12     14     15
2     2     4     8    10     -6     -2      0     14     18     20
3     3     6    12    15     -4      2      5     16     22     25
4     4     8    16    20     -2      6     10     18     26     30
5     5    10    20    25      0     10     15     20     30     35
```

Comment: A little bit more general: `df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("p"), f, .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")) %>% mutate(across(-colnames(df), .fn = list(inf = ~ .x[,1], sup = ~.x[,2])), .keep = "unused") %>% rename_with(.fn = ~ gsub("_1_", "_", .x))`. ;-)

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I assume that this is what `unpack()` does under the hood.